# How to change the color of a RadioButton Ellipse (button's circle and fill) in Maui without creating a ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button, maui

I would like to change the Ellipse (the actual button) border (Stroke property) and Fill colors of a RadioButton by directly setting the appropriate properties of a RadioButton's Ellipse based on the RadioButton's VisualState without having to define a ControlTemplate to do it. Is this possible? It's hard to believe the RadioButton control was designed without providing access to the Ellipse properties but I don't see any way around creating a ControlTemplate.

Here is the boilerplate RadioButton style definition from when I created my current Maui project.

```
 <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="44"/>
        <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="44"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Is there a way to just add something like

```
          <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                 <VisualState.Setters>
                     <Setter Property="EllipseFill" Value="Blue" />
                     <Setter Property="EllipseStroke" Value="Blue" />
                 </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
```

?

Where "EllipseFill" and "EllipseStroke" are replaced by the appropriate statements that target the Ellipse Fill and Stroke properties? As a fallback, is there a way to access the RadioButton's Ellipse and properties through code-behind?

I can certainly create a ControlTemplate if needed. However, it seems there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: It cannot set the appropriate properties of a RadioButton's Ellipse based on the RadioButton's VisualState. But you can try to use Handler to set it.

Answer (score 2):

After wasting a lot of time trying to find a way to do this I just decided that creating my own would be the easier route.

So I have created a skia-based radio button that lets you do pretty much everything you need (at the time of answering this, it's still in pre-release):

Add [FreakyControls](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls) to your Maui project and configure as shown in the docs, Once done you can use the RadioButton as shown below:

```
<freakyControls:FreakyRadioButton
OutlineColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
FillColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
CheckColor="White"
HasCheckAnimation="True"
CheckedChanged="FreakyCheckbox_CheckedChanged"/>
```

I also have RadioGroup based on a StackLayout, the same you can find in the docs.

The Radiobutton is fully customizable, size, colour, outline you name it, it has the feature. If you think something is missing, reach out and I might add it before an official release.

A small preview of it:

[image: Radiobutton Preview]